# validate positive number and invalid date ANGULAR FORM

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

how can i validate an input to be a positive number and date to be no less than the current date? im using angular FormControl/FormBuilder/FormFroup
my code:

html:

```
   <p>Enter price:</p>
    <input type="number" formControlName="couponPrice">
    <div class="alert" *ngIf="!addCouponForm.controls['couponPrice'].valid && 
    addCouponForm.controls['couponPrice'].touched ">{{priceReq}}</div></td>
        <td>
   <p>Enter coupon's start date:</p>
  <input type="date" formControlName="couponStartDate">
  <div class="alert" *ngIf="!addCouponForm.controls['couponStartDate'].valid 
  && addCouponForm.controls['couponStartDate'].touched ">{{startDateReq}} 
  </div>
   </td>
```

component:

```
  this.addCouponForm = fb.group({
  'couponTitle':  [null,[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(20)]],
  'couponStartDate': [null,Validators.required],
  'couponEndDate': [null,Validators.required],
  **'couponAmount': [null,Validators.required],**
  'couponType': [null,Validators.required],
  'couponMessage': [null,[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(20)]],
  **'couponPrice': [null,Validators.required],**
  'couponImage': [null,Validators.required]

})
```

the fields with * are the field i want to make sure user enter a valid number.

thanks a lot

Comment: You can use `Validators.min(0)` to ensure it's positive

Comment: thanks you what about the date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min='0'` for positive number.

and `min="currentDate"` for disable past date.

install `moment` library for date format

`npm install moment --save`

I have a create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/validate-positive-number-and-invalid-date-angular-form-demo-ap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

> component.ts

```
import moment from 'moment';
export class AppComponent implements onInit {

  currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  constructor() {}
}
```

> component.html

```
<input type="number" formControlName="couponPrice" min="0"/>
<input type="date" min="{{currentDate}}" formControlName="couponStartDate"/>
```

Comment: thats work right now thanks .. how can i make sure end date will always be after start date? how can i save the start date value and use it as a min value of end date?